# Data stored into the browser db using pouch db is lost after the browser history is cleared

Tags: html, google-chrome, indexeddb, web-sql, pouchdb

**Background:**

My **HTML5 offline application** stores a lot of data into the local browser database. I use **pouchdb3.3.1** to communicate with the inbrowser database for storing data within the browser. And everything works well in the normal scenario. I am able to store data and retrieve it back when required.

**Issue:**

When the browser history is cleared manually by the user.Then all the data stored in the browser db is cleared. This issue happens in IE11, Chrome36 (these are the browsers that I have in my machine).

Is there a way i could retain the data stored within the browser db when the browser history is cleared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, users are always able to clear the IndexedDB/WebSQL/LocalStorage/AppCache data. In different browsers it's exposed in different ways (e.g. in Firefox it's hidden under Advanced -> Network -> Offline Web Content and User Data), but the capability is always there.

In general you shouldn't expect to have any control over when users decide to clear their browser data, so the best policy with PouchDB is to always sync to a remote database so that the user's data isn't lost.

Answer (score 4):

No.   (thirty character minimum answer length).

Answer (score 1):

I'll re-post this from my presentation about [client side storage](http://denispasovski.github.io/Presentations/HTML5_Client_storage_technologies/index.html#/8):

Data stored on the client side can be lost at any time!